# cmake: Do not install if running a target returns error

Tags: cmake

I build an executable `Myexe` and would like to test run it before deciding to install it. The decision would be based on the `CUSTOM_COMMAND_*` outputs.
How may I do that please?
Here are the steps I take:

```
add_executable(Myexe ${SOURCES}) 
add_custom_command(
        TARGET Myexe
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND Myexe
        DEPENDS MyexeLib
        RESULT_VARIABLE CUSTOM_COMMAND_RESULT
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE CUSTOM_COMMAND_OUTPUT
        ERROR_VARIABLE CUSTOM_COMMAND_ERROR )

install(TARGETS Myexe DESTINATION "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/install/")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a POST_BUILD step fails CMake will delete the executable that has been build. If you use POST_BUILD steps to run the project's tests then any test failure will cause the executable to be deleted. You thus won't be able to debug the test failure with a debbuger, so this is a bad idea.

The way this is usually done instead is to use CTest to run the tests. If all you want to test is that the executable runs (as your current POST_BUILD step suggests) then it is sufficient to add a call to `enable_testing()` in your top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file and then add

```
add_test(
  NAME MyExeTests
  COMMAND Myexe
)
```

in the `CMakeLists.txt` where the `Myexe` target is defined.

To run the tests you then can call

```
ctest --test-dir <build-dir> --output-on-failure
```

before running your regular `cmake --build <build-dir> --target install` or `cmake --install <build-dir>` command you currently use to install your project.

Comment: "_If a POST_BUILD step fails CMake will delete the executable that has been build_" - for my personal learning, where exactly in the docs does it say this? Or is this undocumented behaviour? Or is it generator-specific behaviour?

Comment: @user I'm not sure it is documented, but it makes sense for CMake to behave that way: It the executable were to stay behind it would be up-to-date according to the timestamps of the executable and its dependencies, and thus would not be re-built on the next build invocation, even though the previous build failed.

Comment: @Corristo I  will eventually use enable_testing. Are you implying there is no way to stop installation part based on ctest failed result?

Comment: @rahman Not really. You can make it harder to install without running the tests by adding an additional custom target that depends on the executable's target, but that can also be circumvented. I also don't get why you'd want to prevent someone from installing without running the tests in the first place. For example, what if someone wants to cross-compile? If you want to make sure you yourself don't forget to run the tests before installing you can use a [workflow preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#workflow-preset) and exclusively use that.